# Input has value but ngModel is empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm filling an input with a date picker, works fine and fills date in input, I can get the value of input by logging in console too:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('dateFrom');
elem.value
//returns
2014/12/12
```

but ngModel returns empty string and form validation leads to error. how can I solve this?

**HTML**

```
<form name="roomInfoForm" ng-submit="rooms($event, roomInfoForm.$valid)">   
  // 4 inputs here 
  <input type="text" id="dateFrom" name="dateFrom" ng-model="roomInfo.dateFrom" required  datepicker="#dateFrom">
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.rooms = function (e, isValid) {
  console.log(roomInfo, isValid);
}
```

I have 5 properties on the roomInfo object, 4 properties return value, but only the dateFrom returns the initially defined empty string or null value

Comment: are you using angular date picker modules or directives?

Comment: no, actually it's a plain javascript date picker

Comment: it does not seem to have any problem.  might help if you show more code details. I am guessing the problem is in HTML

Comment: @vdj4y I added more details. thanks

Comment: Not sure when Angular triggers but I guess it might miss a change event or something. Can you reproduce the issue in a Fiddle? Does the model update if you manually click the text input after?

Comment: @Jonathan ok. I try to add Fiddle to question. yes again, Ii updates when in type directly in the input

Comment: If you are using a datepicker library that was not made for Angular, then the digest cycle has probably not been kicked off when the value was changed.  In the dev tools, try running $digest() on the scope from the dev tools, see if that causes it to put the value in the scope.

Comment: Actually, starting a digest cycle doesn't help.  You may need to either fake the event that angular's input directives are listening for, or add your own directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're set on this non-Angular datepicker library, then the ideal approach would be to create your own angular directive (or find one) to wrap around it.  Or, the quick hacky approach would be to trigger a fake 'change' event on the input element.

If you do go down the route of writing a custom directive, then your directive will need to `require: 'ngModel'`.  This will cause the directive's `link` function to be given an NgModelController object as its fourth argument.  Your directive's link function would need to add the necessary listeners to catch events caused by the date picker library changing the value, and call ngModel.$setViewValue to tell angular about the change.

```
.directive('datepicker', function() {
    restrict : 'A',
    require : 'ngModel',
    link : function(scope, el, attrs, ngModel) {
        //...            
        //I'm making some guesses here because I don't know what library you're using.
        el.datepicker({
           onSelect : function(date) {
               ngModel.$setViewValue( date );
           }
           //, ...
        });
        //...     
    }
})
```

https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-using-ngmodel-in-custom-directives
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController

It may be worth checking on ngmodules.org for an existing directive wrapping around your preferred library.
http://ngmodules.org/modules?query=datepicker

Comment: I used an Angular date picker, costs in a heavy library instead of the previous light weight plain JS, but works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to print the input value like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myModel">{{myModel}}

for your code:
<input type="text" id="dateFrom" name="dateFrom" ng-model="roomInfo.dateFrom" 
required  datepicker="#dateFrom"> {{roomInfo.dateFrom}}
```

If the whatever date or value you pick is printed out. it means the scope is working then try to use $timeout.

```
angular.module('app').controller('myCtrl',function($scope,$timeout){
 $scope.rooms = function (e, isValid) {
   $timeout(function(){
     console.log(roomInfo, isValid)
   });
 };
});
```

if your input value is not printed out, your scope is not even linked (which I think it is the case, since your form is invalid)... If the scope is not even linked, then the problem is somewhere else that is not shown here. hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you said that your $scope always return the first initialized value.. I had this one experience. it was very stupid mistake, so i kind of reluctant to mention it. Anyway, what happened is, I attached the controller twice. one in $routeProvider and another one in DOM, as html attributes.

so whenever ng-model is changed, the first controller fire once to $apply the change to scope and then another controller fired which initialized the $scope to original value that i set. 
 I noticed this mistake when I run console.log($scope), it automatically logs twice, both of the log, always prints out the initial set value, not the changed value; eventhough the  element.value has already changed.

Comment: Thanks you. I checked again my code, but it had called my controllers only in $routeProvider, and Also all other fields work fine and only Date doesn't work.